# Kubernetes communication intra-POD

Tags: kubernetes, networking, port, nodes

I have a POD containing a main app and 0 or many sidecars. the sidecars docker images listen to the same port 8080.

```
  - name: sidecar-container-1
    image: sidecar-image-1:latest
    ports:
    - containerPort: 8080

  - name: sidecar-container-2
    image: sidecar-image-2:latest
    ports:
    - containerPort: 8080
```

How can I update the ports to manage the communication from the main app to the sidecars on different ports ?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure I understand what you're asking, but note that all the containers in a pod run in the same network namespace; you can't have multiple things listening on the same port. You would need to modify the application in your sidecar containers to listen on a different port for each container.

Comment: @larsks If I can't change the application port, what options do I have ? 

If I create a service per sidecar container to specify another port, will that work ?

In Docker Compose, we have the possiblity to run the image on another port (other than the app port), isn't the case in k8s ?

Comment: Just run each container in different pod. And connect them with services. and then you can use any port you want ( the services can change the ports but it is not needed if they run in separate pods). Why do you wan to run them in same pod?

Comment: Hello @IgalSerban, Because I wanted to run each main application in its POD with its sidecars. 

So many applications will install the same sidecars, I will need to install each sidecar in its own pod ?

Answer (score 2):

All the containers in a pod run in the same network namespace; you can't have multiple things listening on the same port. You would need to modify the application in your sidecar containers to listen on a different port for each container.

> In Docker Compose, we have the possiblity to run the image on another port (other than the app port), isn't the case in k8s ?

The Docker Compose equivalent of a Kubernetes Pod would look something like this:

```
services:
  infra:
    image: docker.io/google/pause

  container0:
    image: docker.io/alpinelinux/darkhttpd:latest
    network_mode: service:infra

  container1:
    image: docker.io/alpinelinux/darkhttpd:latest
    network_mode: service:infra
```

The key part being that all containers share the same network namespace (using the `network_mode: service:<name>` parameter, which is the equivalent of the `--network container:<container_name_or_id>` option to `docker run`.

Trying to bring up the above compose file will result in one of the containers failing to start:

```
$ docker compose up
[+] Running 4/2
 ✔ Network container_default         Created                                                                             0.1s
 ✔ Container container-infra-1       Created                                                                             0.1s
 ✔ Container container-container1-1  Created                                                                             0.0s
 ✔ Container container-container0-1  Created                                                                             0.0s
Attaching to container-container0-1, container-container1-1, container-infra-1
container-container0-1  | darkhttpd/1.14, copyright (c) 2003-2022 Emil Mikulic.
container-container1-1  | darkhttpd/1.14, copyright (c) 2003-2022 Emil Mikulic.
container-container1-1  | darkhttpd: bind(port 8080): Address in use
container-container1-1 exited with code 1
```

You'll have the same problem trying to start multiple sidecar containers in a Pod with applications attempting to bind to the same port.

---

If you are unable to modify the application image to run on different ports, then as @IgalSerban says in their comment you would need to run the applications in different pods.

We don't have any context for your question; if you can tell us more about what you're trying to accomplish we might be able to provide a better answer.

Comment: Hi, Because I wanted to run each main application in its POD with its sidecars. 

So many applications will install the same sidecars, I will need to install each sidecar in its own pod ?

Comment: Or you will need to configure the sidecars to listen on different ports. You haven't really provided us with enough context to understand what you're doing, so I can't really provide a more concrete suggestion.

Comment: What kind of context do you need ? I don't really have other details other that I have 3 docker images of utilities that listens to the same ports and I'm trying to install them as sidecars for many applications, so I thought it will be a POD per main application and its sidecars